# Select Only Those Items That Appear Only In Each Table Of Two MySQL Databases

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I have two databases which started as the same some time ago. These now need merging into one. To avoid duplication I want to delete entries that are in both from the second. If I run the query below it automatically removes duplicates:-

```
SELECT idClient, LastName, FirstName
   FROM `ABC`.`Client`
   WHERE idClient > 1000
UNION
SELECT  idClient, LastName, FirstName
   FROM `XYZ`.`Client`
   WHERE idClient > 1000;
```

However, the only entries I want returned are the ones which are duplicated but cannot work out the syntax to achieve this.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support INTERSECT @RadimBača

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the ones that are duplicated, you can use `exists`:

```
SELECT idClient, LastName, FirstName
FROM `ABC`.`Client` ac
WHERE idClient > 1000 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM `XYZ`.`Client` xc
              WHERE xc.idClient = ac.idClient AND xc.LastName = ac.LastName AND
                    xc.FirstName = ac.FirstName AND
                    xc.idClient > 1000
             );
```

Note:  This will not return columns that have `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT idClient, LastName, FirstName
FROM `ABC`.`Client` a
JOIN `XYZ`.`Client` b ON a.idClient = b.idClient AND a.LastName = b.LastName AND a.FirstName = b.FirstName
WHERE a.idClient > 1000
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support INTERSECT

Comment: @RaymondNijland true, I have updated the answer. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: don't need "and b.idclient >1000" because b.idclient has to equal a.idclient and a.idclient has to be > 1000